# Double data type confusion - redeemed

Tags: java, double

A question of mine was recently closed as a duplicate, but that didn't help me completely. My new and a more specific question is:

Can all values(whole numbers, without any decimal part) smaller than 1.7e308 and greater than 0 be stored in a *double* data type, as 1.7e308 is the maximum value of a *double* data type? Because I don't want a decimal numeral, but a large, non-decimal number so large that can't be represented even by long long.

Comment: No, not all of them can.

Comment: There is only about 2^63 positive double values and 10^308 integers less than the maximum value. You can't encode more values than a 64-bit can store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can all whole numbers smaller than 1.7e308 and greater than 0 be stored in a double data type

The simple answer is No.

There are various ways to come to this conclusion, but here is one that doesn't even depend on an understanding of floating point number formats.

1. We know that `double` is a 64 bit representation.
2. Therefore, there can be at most 2<sup>64</sup> distinct `double` values: that is about 1.8 x 10<sup>19</sup>
3. You are asking if a `double` can represent all integers between zero and 1.7 x 10<sup>308</sup>.
4. That is 1.7 x 10<sup>308</sup> *distinct* values.
5. 1.7 x 10<sup>308</sup> is greater than 1.8 x 10<sup>19</sup>.
6. Therefore what you are asking is impossible.

Your best simple option is to use `BigInteger`.

But you said this:

> ... but due to slow operations on BigIntegers, I'm keeping it a last choice. It takes about a second to multiply two 4-digit numbers.

That is simply not true.  If you have come to that conclusion by benchmarking, then there is something very wrong with your methodology.

Multiplying 2 x 4 digit numbers using `BigInteger` should take less than a microsecond.

Comment: Thanks, and I once again checked what I said. Actually it was multiplying two 11-digit numbers that took about a second. And this answer completely cleared all my doubts, thanks again.

Comment: Once again, if it is taking that long, you are not measuring it correctly,

Answer (score 0):

All floating type numbers (halfs/floats/doubles/long doubles/etc) are composed of  a mantissa and an exponent.

Suppose you have `1.7e308`, `1.7` is the mantissa while `308` is the exponent. You can't exactly separate the two in a float. This is because every float is represented as a composition of the aforementioned in memory. Hence you can't have a "non-decimal" float.

Comment: Ok then so are there any numbers (like 647373736472829274.00 and a lot greater than this) which can't be represented/stored in a double?

Comment: `java.math.BigInteger` might be what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, I know about that, I even tried it, but due to slow operations on BigIntegers, I'm keeping it a last choice. It takes about a second to multiply two 4-digit numbers.